# Cannot call method in child class that implements from interface

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597910/2874163) i tried to implement it like this

Abstract class (Pilot):

```
public abstract class Pilot{
    abstract void fly();
}
```

Interface (Safety Officer):

```
public interface ISafetyOfficer {
        void controlSafety();
}
```

Child class:

```
public class C141 extends Pilot implements ISafetyOfficer{
    void fly(){ 
        System.out.println("I'm flying C-141.");
    }

    public void controlSafety(){
        System.out.println("I'm control safety.");
    }
```

and in `main()` of Main class that cannot call `controlSafety()` method

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pilot pilot = new C141();
        pilot.fly();
        pilot.controlSafety(); // Cannot call controlSafty here.
    }
}
```

The problem occurred in function `main()`. Can anyone tell me why i can't call `controlSafety()` method in OOP way.

Comment: If you want to use the `controlSafety()` method using a Pilot reference, the Pilot class has to implement the `ISafetyOfficer` interface or define the method itself. As the Pilot class is abstract, you don't need to provide and implementation on the Pilot class but every non-abstract subclass of Pilot will require to provide an implementation for the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, because the `controlSafety` is not one of the characteristics of the the `Pilot` class. so when you trying to call the `controlSafety` from a `Pilot` declared object, the compiler checks if its declared inside the `Pilot` class, if not it not allow you to call it.

So `C141` is a `Pilot` also is a `ISafetyOfficer`.

But the `Pilot` is not `ISafetyOfficer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the C141 to an ISafetyOfficer and then call it. Java is not a duck typed language.

Comment: but `C141` extends from `Pilot` .

Answer (score 0):

Because you upcast the C141 class to the Pilot abstract class. But Pilot class does not have controlSafety() method.

Answer (score 0):

`Pilot` class don't have method `controlSafety()` that's why compiler don't find that method.

`Pilot pilot = new C141()` It is polymorphism but only method present in `Pilot` class will be call not from method interface `ISafetyOfficer` get called.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand/reference variable of the statement `Pilot pilot = new C141();` determines what methods can be called on the object assigned to it. In this case its of type `Pilot`, and since `Pilot` class does not have method `controlSafety()` it cannot be invoked using reference of type `Pilot`. You can do a workaround in such cases by type casting:-

```
  Pilot pilot = new C141();
  pilot.fly();
  C141 c=(C141)pilot;
  c.controlSafety();
  //or
  ISafetyOfficer isafe=(ISafetyOfficer)pilot;
  isafe.controlSafety();
```

Also from OOP pov , the pilot is meant to fly and not to control safety , thats what Isafety officer is for, hence you cannot tell pilot to do controlSafety. The ideal way should be:-

```
  Pilot pilot = new C141();
  pilot.fly();
  ISafetyOfficer isafe=new C141();
  isafe.controlSafety();
```